# Is there a way I could factor out $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I need to know $\det M$

$$M = 3B + BT$$

where $T=\begin{pmatrix} k-3 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & k \\ 0 & k & -3\end{pmatrix}$

and I know that $\det B = 5$

is there any way I could factor out $B$ on my original equation?

this are all $3 \times 3$ matrices, and I need to find out the value of $k$ so that $M$ is invertible

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use mathjax to make your questions more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  We have
$$
3B + BT = B(3I) + BT = B(3I + T)
$$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

Comment: ohh nice! thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

$$M=3B+BT$$
yes you can take B common as below
$$M=B(3I_n+T)$$
$$det(M)=det(B)\times det(3I_3+T)$$
M is invertible that means 
$$det(M)\neq 0$$
or
$$det(3I_3+T)\neq 0$$
$$det(\begin{bmatrix}k-3&2&0\\2&0&k\\0&k&-3\end{bmatrix}+3\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix})\neq 0$$
$$det(\begin{bmatrix}k&2&0\\2&3&k\\0&k&0\end{bmatrix})\neq 0$$
$$-k^3\neq 0$$
$$k\neq 0$$

Comment: just got the same answer! thank u! :3